# Set size of scroll thumb?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'v looked on MSDN and can't find how to do this. It lets me set the range and position but not the thumb that the user clicks and drags.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the scroll page size, so it calculates the proportional size of the bar given the range and page size.  Look at [SetScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787595(VS.85).aspx) and related functions.